# How to embed a SWT TableViewer in a TabFolder?

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer, tabbed-view

I am trying to embed a JFace [TableViewer](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) in a SWT [TabFolder](http://www.jdocs.com/swt/3.1/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TabFolder.html), but when I do so, the table does not show up. The current (working code) in my [GitToDo](http://github.com/egonw/gtd/blob/master/com.github.gittodo.rcp/src/com/github/gittodo/rcp/GitToDo.java) code looks like (see [this Git repos](http://github.com/egonw/gtd/tree/master/com.github.gittodo.rcp/)):

```
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Git ToDo");
    FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
    shell.setLayout(layout);

    final GitToDoTree tableViewer = new GitToDoTree(shell);
```

Where the latter [GitToDoTree](http://github.com/egonw/gtd/blob/master/com.github.gittodo.rcp/src/com/github/gittodo/rcp/views/GitToDoTree.java) *extends TableViewer*, with this constructor:

```
    super(parent, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.FILL);
    this.shell = parent;
    table = this.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
```

So, when I construct the TableViewer-extending GitToDoTree from a Shell it works, but as soon as I try to build it from a TabFolder or (tried that too) a Composite, nothing shows up anymore.

How can I get my TableViewer to show up in the TabFolder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your TableViewer class isn't showing up when you add it to a `Composite` I would say that chances are that you are not setting a layout for the nested `Composite`.

```
final Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setText("Git ToDo");
FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
shell.setLayout(layout);

Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(new FillLayout()); // Possible missing layout?

final GitToDoTree tableViewer = new GitToDoTree(composite);
```

And as for the TabFolder that may be that you are not setting the client control on the TabItem

```
TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.NONE);
TabItem item = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("Table");

GitToDoTree viewer = new GitToDoTree(tabFolder);
item.setControl(viewer.getTable()); // Possible setControl call?

TabItem item2= new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
item2.setText("Empty");
```

Comment: See commit: http://github.com/egonw/gtd/commit/4d198e5cbe796ea8430f42eb397d366064d1b1e5